# My laptop can't access files from my desktop

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, laptop

Here is my problem. I have a desktop, a laptop and a typical router. The desktop is connected through wire and I connected my laptop wirelessly.

I can access my desktop files through my laptop, but I can't access shared files from my laptop through the desktop.

**I can read/write files from laptop to desktop but not from desktop to laptop.**

When I access the laptop through the desktop it only shows the login window, but if I access the desktop through my laptop I can see the files.

Comment: did you check your laptop firewall?

Comment: Can you say what OS both the desktop and the laptop have? I'm thinking it is a matter of setting up the right permissions.

Comment: @Jaime: Since you mentioned that accessing laptop from desktop it shows login window - can you login using your laptop credentials and see your files?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a Sharing issue on your laptop.

click on your wireless icon -> Open Network and Sharing Centre -> Change Advanced sharing settings (in left column) and make sure that the following are on for 'Home or work' off for public;

Turn on Network Discovery
Turn on File and printer sharing

That should allow 2 way sharing.

If in doubt, check this link;

[Windows 7 HomeGroup: Walkthrough](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee449416%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Hope this resolves it.

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

On the files you want to be able to read and write do the following:

- Right click on them
- Scroll down to properties
- Click on the security tab at the top

Then you will have the options of who can either modify, read, write, full control, special permissions and so on.